# 〈 前のenスペースにヒットする正規表現

Tags: 正規表現, indesign

〈の前にくるenスペースのみにヒットさせる正規表現がわかりません。
※「(『などは含まず〈のみです。

例)ステーキが食べたい   〈2000円以内で〉
     ↑この文でいう『い』と『〈』の間にあるenスペース部分です。『〈』は含みません。

インデザインの正規表現を使用しています。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

手近に動作環境がないので確認まではできませんが、InDesignの正規表現についてちょっと調べてみました。

こちらはアドビのフォーラムへの[ユーザー投稿](https://forums.adobe.com/docs/DOC-8795)のようですが、肯定先読み(`(?=パターン)`)が使えるようですね。これを使うと、文字と文字の間に立ち止まってその先になにかがあることを確認することができます。(立ち止まっているのでマッチ結果には含まれません)

あと、公式のものではありませんが、[CS3の正規表現まとめ記事](http://www.seuzo.jp/st/Other/InDesign_regex.html)によると en space は `~>` と書くようです。(とはいえ、入力できるなら直に書いてもよいはず）

さて、「`〈`の前にくる`enスペース`」は読み替えると「次が`〈`である`enスペース`」ということですので、 `~>(?=〈)` になるのかな。